# MySQL update with group by error

Tags: mysql

Current I have 3 account are use the same email address and I would like to giving a hash key for the same email address with group by function. The sql statement running is

```
UPDATE customers (
    SELECT customer_id, email, email_hash FROM customers GROUP BY email) AS t1
    SET email_hash='123' WHERE email='abc@abc.com'
```

when i run this sql query i'm getting this error.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(select customer_id, email, email_hash, email_reg_status from customers group by' at line 1
```

what can i do using the group by function to insert same hash key for the same email address?

Comment: You can't update a table from which you're selecting from.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct all you need to do is

```
update customers set email_hash='123' where email='abc@abc.com';
```

Comment: i don't think this can work as my `customers` table have same email address and i would like to insert the same `hash key` to the same email.

Comment: My query will update all rows that have that email, not just one. Update works that way.

Comment: The information are existed in my table and I'm just created a new field for the table, and I'm the `loop` to generate all the hash key.

Comment: Yes. You have new empty field for email_hash that you need to populate. This query will update the hash for ALL customers with an email of 'abc@abc.com' to be '123'. That is probably what you want. If not, update the question to better explain.

Comment: For the hash key I'm using `md5` to generate not input own hash key. So I don't know which what hash key I'm generate to which account.

Answer (score 0):

Since `email_id` is same for all customers; if you do like below then all your customer record will have same value in `email_hash`

```
update customers set email_hash='123' where email='abc@abc.com';
```

I assume that at least your `customer_id` field is unique. In that case why not just update by the `customer_id` which is unique like below

```
UPDATE customers SET email_hash='123' WHERE customer_id=<some_id_value>
```

Comment: Actually I'm doing this in `loop` statement since I just created a new field for my database table.

Comment: In that case, use `cursor` and for each `customer_id` update your `hash` value.